# How can I modify my PHP code for gethint?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am studying the [PHP/Ajax functions at W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp). That source code is amazing to me. But that code doesn't have the hyperlinking function. So I want to make a hyperlink from the q parameter from a URL.

So I make PHP code for this purpose. But I am at a loss for a long time.
Below is my PHP code.

```
// Get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$hint = "";

// Lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "")
{
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len = strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name)
    {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len)))
        {
            if ($hint === "")
            {
                $hint = $name;
                echo '<a href="http://www.naver.com/"'$hint">" $hint"</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                $hint .= ", echo '<a href="http://www.naver.com/"'$hint">"  $hint"</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or output the correct values
echo $hint==="" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

How can I make a href="http://www... hyperlink $hint or $name?

Comment: Do not use w3schools, please see this link for more http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to print a URL:

```
echo '< a href="http://www.naver.com/"'.$hint.">".$hint."< /a>"; 
$hint='< a href="http://www.naver.com/"'.$hint.">".$hint."< /a>";
```

Comment: Really I appreciate your kind coding.